# Gradle failed to refresh

Tags: java, android

Everytime I try to add, `compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'`
I get the following error

```
Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Users\De Untouchable\AndroidStudioProjects\Yora\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\De Untouchable\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_3aewj3nvnlp7huq0b8xvs2ju1\ProjectScript\buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 5744
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: C:\Users\De Untouchable\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_3aewj3nvnlp7huq0b8xvs2ju1\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock
```

Comment: It is currently in use by another Gradle instance. means another gradle process is using resources.

Comment: Stop all gradle instances and try again.

Comment: You can try `taskkill /f /pid 5744` in command line and remove `cache.properties.lock` then try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clear your gradle cache -> delete the whole `.gradle` folder -> project directory. don't worry it will be recreated. The same is for `.gradle` -> home directory.

you can also go to File -> Invalidate ->Caches/Restart.