# Android Studio Working with Sample Projects but Gradle Timeout for every New Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently installed Android Studio but when I try to create a new project gradle failed and timeout error raised. I am not good in the Android Studio. if I try to sample project everything working fine. but I can not start a new project or even cannot use a github project. gradle is really annoying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133518/how-to-update-android-studio-automatically

Comment: Did your anti-virus block Android Studio?

Comment: no i dont have anti virus installed in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be firewall issue and also check your internet connection. try turning off your firewall.
you can also set offline gradle by changing
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Check Offline work under Global Gradle settings

check if your issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724682/gradle-failed-to-refresh)

Comment: i have tried everything like turning off firewall and adding Android Studio .exe to firewall also tried to make gradle offline. Nothing working only sample projects are working perfectly. Why sample projects are working if android studio has misconfigured??